# Writing progress bar into file

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar

I have subprocess which has redirected stdout and stderr to file:

```
file = open(self._file_path, 'w+')
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=file, stderr=file)
```

Subprocess is writing progress bar into stdout:

```
sys.stdout.write('\r{0:.2f}%'.format(float(self.counter)/self.count*100))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

But carriage return is not working and result is:

```
3.23%
6.45%
9.68%
...
100.00%
```

Without stdout redirection to file (using subprocess.PIPE instead) all works fine in console and I'm getting progress on the same line.

Comment: Yes, that's how carriage returns are usually rendered when you view a file in a text editor. What's your question?

Comment: I want updating progress line with new value of progress without jump on line line. My question is how to do that with stdout redirection into file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the file to work similar to console, delete the contents of the file before writing the new output or use seek() method to go to the beginning of the line